# Data array to send Push Notification in project PHP for android / ios

Tags: php, android, ios, laravel, push-notification

Notifications are sent, no problem mais I wish to have a badge on the notifications it is never used, I went through all the firebase documentation nothing to do. As is the keyword field.

Package used : edujugon/push-notification:4.5

```
    $devices[] = $deviceData['id'];

    $push = new PushNotification('fcm');
    $push->setMessage([
        'notification' => [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'badge' => $this->badge,
        ],
    ])
        ->setApiKey($this->apiKeyFirebase)
        ->setDevicesToken($devices)
        ->send();
```

With this array sent, I am not receiving the notification under IOS, so the feedback from the ios server tells me that the notification has been sent, there must be a problem with the keys to my array that I am sending, I don’t haven't found, would anyone know?

```
    $devices[] = $deviceData['id'];

    $push = new PushNotification('apn');
    $push->setMessage([
        'aps' => [
            'alert' => [
                'title' => $this->title,
                'body' => $this->body,
            ],
            'badge' => $this->badge,
        ],
    ])
        ->setConfig($this->getConfig())
        ->setDevicesToken($devices)
        ->send();
```

Comment: Make sure certificates are set up correctly. Try using `getFeedback()` method after `send()` to see if there is a response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the feedback :

```
object(stdClass)#157 (3) {
  ["success"]=>
  int(1)
  ["failure"]=>
  int(0)
  ["tokenFailList"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

It tells me sucess true but i am not getting the notification on ios, it is not visible

Answer (score 0):

With the library sly/notification-pusher, i received push notif ios but i have not title :(

```
    $messages = [$this->body];

    $params = ['title' => $this->title];

    $pushNotificationService = new ApnsPushService(
        $certificatePath, $passPhrase, PushManager::ENVIRONMENT_PROD
    );

    $response = $pushNotificationService->push($devices, $messages, [
        'aps' => [
            'alert' => [
                'title' => $this->title,
                'body' => $this->body,
            ],
            'badge' => $this->badge,
        ]
    ]);
```